# Urban Dictionary API in discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord.py

So I am new to API's and I don't know how to solve this. This is my code so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from aiohttp import ClientSession

class Dictionary(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot=bot


    @commands.command(
        name="Urban dictionary",
        aliases=["urban", "urband"]
    )
    async def urbandictionary(self, ctx, term):
        url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"
        querystring = {"term":term}

        headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "My Key"
        }
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring) as response:
                r = await response.json()
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"First result for:{term}", description=None)
                embed.add_field(name=f"{r({'definition'})}", value=None, inline=False)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Dictionary(bot))
```

I tried printing "r", and a lot of json pops up. How do I make it, so the first definition shows up, and also not in the terminal, but in the discord chat?

The JSON looks like this in the terminal: https://pastebin.com/j5TPZBeA

Comment: The `r` variable is a python dictionary, you can use it like a regular one, also another thing, you shouldn't create a new aiohttp session everytime someone invokes the command, you should have a static one that will make all the requests altogether. If you showed us the format of the json response maybe we could help, but there's nothing we can do at the moment

Comment: I updated it, I put it on pastebin, since it's too long for stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Getting the Definition

You're on the right track, but you're not indexing the returned JSON `dict` correctly:

```
r({'definition'})
```

`dict` objects aren't callable, nor do you index them with curly brackets. Even still, based on the structure of the returned JSON, this wouldn't get you to the definition anyway. Since the payload is **minified** JSON, a tool to view it in a nicer format makes it much easier to figure out, such as [this browser-based tool](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) or [`jq` for the command-line](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Now we can can clearly see how the JSON is structured:

[image: Prettified JSON in a tree view]

So in this payload, there's a root key called `'list'` that holds an array of definitions. To get the first definition and add it as a field to your embed:

```py
definition = r['list'][0]['definition']
embed.add_field(name=term, value=definition, inline=False)
```

#### Sending a Message

To actually send this definition to a text channel, you simply need to call the [`send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) method on your Cog's `ctx`, passing in your `embed`:

```
ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for figuring this out :)